# issue to delete an array item form json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code for moving one array item to another.

```
var data={"Used":[{"Items":[{"ID":1,"Name":"item1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"item1"}]}],"UnUsed":[{"Items":[]}]};    
data.UnUsed[0].Items.splice(0,0,data.Used[0].Items);    
var len=data.Used[0].Items.length;  
for(i=0;i<len;i++)  
{
    data.Used[0].Items.splice(0,1);
}   
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Current Output is:

```
{"Used":[{"Items":[]}],"UnUsed":[{"Items":[[]]}]}
```

Expected Output is:

```
{"Used":[{"Items":[]}],"UnUsed":[{"Items":[[{"ID":1,"Name":"item1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"item1"}]]}]}
```

Comment: You want to move all `Items` from `Used` to `Unused`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to move all item from Used to UnUsed.

Comment: Then maybe like: `data.UnUsed[0].items = data.Used[0].items.slice(0); data.Used[0].items = [];`

Comment: if i use above code, i am getting this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined '.

Comment: You don't need to use slice/splice. Take a look at my answer and demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/K3cz3/

```
var data={"Used":[{"Items":[{"ID":1,"Name":"item1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"item1"}]}],"UnUsed":[{"Items":[]}]};    
var len = data.Used[0].Items.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    data.UnUsed[0].Items.splice(0, 0, data.Used[0].Items[0]);
    data.Used[0].Items.splice(0, 1);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

### Edit:

Here's a better one that makes it more clear what's happening:

```
var len = data.Used[0].Items.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    data.UnUsed[0].Items.push(data.Used[0].Items.pop());
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K3cz3/1/

Or simply:

```
data.UnUsed[0].Items = data.Used[0].Items;
data.Used[0].Items = [];
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K3cz3/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way - saves having to splice all over the shop.

```
data.UnUsed[0].Items = data.Used[0].Items;
data.Used[0].Items = [];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/3Kq2D/3/)